# Dependency injection in custom attribute

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I have a custom attribute that gets 2 parameters, how can I inject this parameters to `MyAttribute` ?

```
public class MyAttribute : Attribute
{
    private readonly HttpContextAccessor _accessor;
    private readonly IUserService _userService;


    public MyAttribute(HttpContextAccessor accessor, IUserService userService)
    {
        _accessor = accessor; 
        _userService = userService;
        // ...
    }
}
```

controller:

```
[MyAttribute()]
[Route("/action")]
public IActionResult Action()
{
   retuen View();
}
```

Comment: you can search for `ServiceFilterAttribute` and `TypeFilterAttribute`, actually a custom `IFilterFactory` can be used as well.

Comment: This article is pretty great and covers most of the relevant options: https://www.devtrends.co.uk/blog/dependency-injection-in-action-filters-in-asp.net-core

Comment: @mohammad please check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4102138/how-to-use-dependency-injection-with-an-attribute

Comment: According to mentioned link, don't inject in a attribute, please check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29915192/dependency-injection-in-attributes

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Firstly,you need inject `IHttpContextAccessor` instead of `HttpContextAccessor`.

Secondly,service is not a valid attribute parameter type.I suggest that you could use `ActionFilterAttribute` or any other `Attribute`(It depends on your detailed scenario) which could cast to `ServiceFilterAttribute` or `TypeFilterAttribute`.

Here is a whole working demo:

Custom ActionFilterAttribute:

```
public class MyAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _accessor;
    private readonly IUserService _userService;


    public MyAttribute(IHttpContextAccessor accessor, IUserService userService)
    {
        _accessor = accessor;
        _userService = userService;
    }
}
```

Controller:

```
//[ServiceFilter(typeof(MyAttribute))]
[TypeFilter(typeof(MyAttribute))]
public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
{          
    return View();
}
```

Register services:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddHttpContextAccessor();
    services.AddScoped<IUserService, UserService>();
    services.AddScoped<MyAttribute>();          
}
```

Reference:

[get values from class and method attribute in middleware in asp.net core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65659571/get-values-from-class-and-method-attribute-in-middleware-in-asp-net-core)